# How to change an integer from an arraylist without it losing its order in that list

Tags: java, arraylist

So I want to subtract 1 from a specific number in an arraylist. However doing it the way below it makes it lose its place to the next number.

```
      int x = 0;    
      ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();   
      values.add(4);
      values.add(8);
      x = values.get(0) - 1;
      values.remove(0);
      values.add(x);
```

How do I go around changing `values.get(0)` without having `values.get(1)` get its place when i remove the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to update the first value by subtracting one. That is, `4` should be become `3` and the `values` should change from `4,8` to `3,8`. You should call [`List.set(int, E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) instead of `remove`. Like,

```
values.set(0, values.get(0) - 1);
System.out.println(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(4);
    values.add(8);
    values.set(0,values.get(0)-1);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Java stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html). The approach is: get the index of `x` and use it to set the value back in the position in List. If you want to subtract only the certain `index`, you can use `.filter`

```
    List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.add(4);
    values.add(8);

    values.stream().forEach(x -> {
        values.set(values.indexOf(x), x - 1);
    });
    System.out.println(values); // [3, 7]
```

Note: You can get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` if doing it using `enhanced for loop`.